# Widgets+QML Android

Tags: qt, qml, qwidget, qquickview, qquickwidget

everyone!

For my application I need to use QGraphicsView and the QML interface.

For this I have two ways:

1. QQuickWidget.
2. QQuickView + QWidget::createWindowContainer

But for the two approaches I have problems.

1. Everything works on Windows but TextField doesn't work when using the standard Android emulator. No input cursor and no keyboard appears, the component is just not active. Strangely enough SpinBox and TextInput, buttons and everything else works.
   But if I create a simple application using only Qt Quick, everything works fine! What can be the problem?
2. The second way is more preferable for me. Everything works on Windows. But I have problems on Android emulator too. In this case, all QML components are not active, they do not respond to clicks. Please tell me what could be the problem?

I use Qt 6.5, Qt Creator with CMake and Emulator for "7inn WSVGA (Tablet)" Android 12.0 (S) (SDK 31) x86_64

I tried ui->quickWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
But it doesn't work